# Visual Studio 2022 - C++ - cannot find compiler options window

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I created an empty C++ project to do some c++ training

I get this error as I build, so **I want to upgrade my compiler to latest or at least 17**

**error C7529: multiple using-declarators require at least '/std:c++17'**

- I just cannot find the **regular compiler options window/ui**
- I looked everywhere, all I get is some sort of JSON config file

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "msvc_x64"
      ],
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "includePath": [
        "${env.INCLUDE}",
        "${workspaceRoot}\\**"
      ],
      "defines": [
        "WIN32",
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
    }
  ]
}
```

thanks for your help on this

[edit]

[vs start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY6yk.png)

[vs2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwpEK.png)

[vs2022 about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tatVR.png)

Comment: This json config makes me think that you are actually using Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: You seem to be confused between VSCode and Visual Studio, which is it (could be both of course)?

Comment: ... and this is why you should be using Visual Studio proper - it's much better.  The community edition is a free download.

Comment: Maybe you are reading documentation for Visual Studio, but are actually using Visual Studio Code (VS Code)? That's my best guess.

Comment: nope, added a screenshot, it's vs2022
please stop downvoting my question, check the screenshots, it is vs 2022
give it a try and trust me. been developing for >30years, I know the difference between VS and VS-code

Comment: can you guys help me out ? this question is legit

Comment: right click "cpptraining.vxproj" and select "properties" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-170

Comment: ok figured it out. I opened the folder instead of the solution. my bad

Answer (score 1):

ok figured it out. I opened the folder instead of the solution. my bad

[select open solution, not open folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ5a5.png)